# Выгрузка на лист части массива

Tags: excel, vba

Есть массив *Massive(1 to N, 1 to M)*.

Есть ли способ выгрузки на лист *Excel* части массива без перебора в цикле (к примеру, выгрузить только вторую колонку массива)?

Comment: Ну разве что выгрузить на лист весь массив, а потом удалить ненужные колонки... как вариант создать лист, выгрузить массив, скопировать нужную колонку, удалить лист - это может оказаться быстрее.

Comment: Спасибо, за совет. Это рабочий вариант, но я так делать точно не буду.

Comment: Ну тогда Вам не повезло... это не массив массивов, а двумерный массив, и отдельные его колонки не являются самостоятельными примитивами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция листа *ИНДЕКС (INDEX)*:

```
ИНДЕКС(диапазон;строка;столбец)
```

Функция позволяет выбрать из диапазона значение ячейки, расположенной на пересечении указанных строки и столбца. Если не указывать строку/столбец или указать 0 (ноль), то функция создаст массив из строк/столбцов указанного столбца/строки:

```
=ИНДЕКС(диапазон;;12)
=ИНДЕКС(диапазон;5;0)
```

Функцию можно использовать в *VBA* для извлечения части массива:

```
Sub PartOfTheArray()
Dim ar(1 To 20, 1 To 5)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To 20
        For j = 1 To 5
            ar(i, j) = i + j * 0.01
        Next j
    Next i

    ' ======= примеры выгрузки части массива ======= '
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(20, 1).Value = ar ' столбец 1 '
    Cells(1, 2).Resize(20, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ar, 0, 2) ' столбец 2 '
    Cells(1, 3).Resize(10, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ar, 0, 4) ' неполный столбец 4 '
    Cells(1, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value = ar ' строка 1 '
    Cells(2, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ar, 7, 0) ' строка 7 '
    Cells(3, 4).Resize(1, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ar, 9, 0) ' неполная строка 9 '
End Sub
```